# How I can use single log4j for multiple modules?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I have multiple java project and all are having separate log4j configuration. But i want to single log4j for all modules so that if there is a change in log4j then no need to update all log4j files.
So if i put common properties in one file and modules specific properties in another file and at the run time i want to merge both files and create single log4j file.

Answer (score 0):

My tip is not to do it. Usually logs are separated because they need to be , for multiple reasons:

- for easier getting around them after issue
- because they logically are meant to be separated since they cover
  different code
- tracking from which service did the issue come etc